# Can I show in this theory that every ill-founded set is equipollent to some well-founded set?

Tags: set-theory

In the theory $Z-\text{Foundation}$ can I prove that every ill-founded set is equipollent to some well-founded set?

Comment: Not even with Replacement. (Note that Choice is notably missing from Z.)

Comment: Check the comments right after Ex.II.9.3 of Kunen's new [book](http://www.collegepublications.co.uk/logic/mlf/?00016). There it is shown that $\mathit{ZF}-$Foundation$+\mathit{AC}^{\mathsf{WF}}+\neg\mathit{AC}$ is consistent.